# Call a stored procedure that requires parameters without parameters?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

can I somehow call a stored proc without params, even though it normally has params?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can, recreate the SPROC with default parameters

```
CREATE PROC myproc(@param1 AS INT = 0, @param2 AS VARCHAR(20) = '')
```

etc

Answer (score 3):

You can if you set the params in the stored proc to have a default value. Then you don't have to pass them.

EDIT:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [ProcName]
(
    @filterId int = NULL
)
```

Doing this will eliminate the need to have to pass it. Though you can if you want to.